# Processing example files with roxygen2: backslashes are duplicated (\dontrun becomes \\dontrun)

Tags: r, roxygen, roxygen2

### Actual question

How can I avoid that `\dontrun{` in a **separate file** containing examples becomes `\\dontrun{` in the respective Rd file after roxygenizing?

I did find a workaround, but feel as if I'm maybe just missing something obvious, i.e. some setting of `roxigenize()`.

### Details

I think I noticed a possible bug or, IMHO, at least an undesired behavior when processing examples with [roxygen2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html) that are stored in a **separate file** (as opposed to stating it right within the actual roxygen code).

The issue is that the line `\dontrun{` in the respective example files becomes `\\dontrun{` in the resulting Rd file after roxygenizing.

Below you'll find an illustration of the behavior along with a simple workaround

### 1) Ensure directories

```
dir.create("src", recursive=TRUE, showWarnings=FALSE)
dir.create("package", recursive=TRUE, showWarnings=FALSE)

# Ensure empty package directory
subdirs <- list.files("package", full.names=TRUE)
if (length(subdirs)) {
    sapply(subdirs, unlink, recursive=TRUE)
}
```

### 2) Create example functions with two different ways of embedding examples

```
foo1 <- function(x) {message("I'm foo #1"); return(TRUE)}
roxy.1 <- c(
    "#' Title foo1()",
    "#'", 
    "#' Description foo1().",
    "##' This line is commented out",
    "#'", 
    "#' @param x Some R object that doesn't matter.",
    "#' @return \\code{TRUE}.",
    "#' @references \\url{http://www.something.com/}",
    "#' @author John Doe \\email{john.doe@@something.com}",
    "#' @seealso \\code{\\link{foo2}}",
    "#' @example inst/examples/foo1.R"
)
ex.1 <- c(
    "\\dontrun{",
    "foo1()",
    "}"
)

foo2 <- function(y) {message("I'm foo #2"); return(FALSE)}
roxy.2 <- c(
    "#' Title foo2()",
    "#'", 
    "#' Description foo2().",
    "##' This line is commented out",
    "#'", 
    "#' @param y Some R object that doesn't matter.",
    "#' @return \\code{FALSE}.",
    "#' @references \\url{http://www.something.com/}",
    "#' @author John Doe \\email{john.doe@@something.com}",
    "#' @seealso \\code{\\link{foo1}}",
    "#' @examples", 
    "#' \\dontrun{",
    "#' foo2()}",
    "#' }"
)

write(roxy.1, file="src/foo1.R")
write(c("foo1 <-", deparse(foo1)), file="src/foo1.R", append=TRUE)
write(roxy.2, file="src/foo2.R")
write(c("foo2 <-", deparse(foo2)), file="src/foo2.R", append=TRUE)
```

### 3) Create package skeleton

```
package.skeleton(name="test", path="package", 
    code_files=c("src/foo1.R", "src/foo2.R"))
```

### 4) Create separate example file for `foo1()`

```
dir.create("package/test/inst/examples", recursive=TRUE, showWarnings=FALSE)
write(ex.1, file="package/test/inst/examples/foo1.R")
```

### 5) Roxygenize

```
require("roxygen2")
roxygenize(
    package.dir="package/test",
    overwrite=TRUE, 
    unlink.target=FALSE,
    roclets = c("collate", "namespace", "rd")
)
```

### 6) Check package

```
shell("R CMD check package/test", intern=FALSE)
```

Truncated output of R CMD check which shows that there's a problem with `\dontrun{` in `./package/test/man/foo1.Rd`

```
[...]
Warning: parse error in file 'test-Ex.R':
1: unexpected input
19: 
20: \
    ^
* checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in 'test-Ex.R' failed
The error most likely occurred in:

> ### Name: foo1
> ### Title: Title foo1()
> ### Aliases: foo1
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
> \dontrun{
Error: unexpected input in "\"
Execution halted
Warning message:
In shell(expr, intern = FALSE) :
  'R CMD check package/test' execution failed with error code 1
>
```

### 7) Workaround

```
patchRdFiles <- function( 
    path="package",
    name,
    ...
) {
    path <- file.path(path, name, "man")
    if (!file.exists(path)) {
        stop(paste("Invalid directory path: '", path, "'", sep=""))
    }
    files <- list.files(path, full.names=TRUE)  
#ii=files[1]    
    .dead <- sapply(files, function(ii) {
        cnt <- readLines(ii, warn=FALSE)
        if (length(grep("\\\\\\\\dontrun", cnt, perl=TRUE))) {
            message(paste("Correcting: '", ii, "'", sep=""))
            write(gsub("\\\\dontrun", "\\dontrun", cnt), file=ii)
        }
        return(NULL)
    })
    return(TRUE)
}
```

This will remove all duplicated backslashes in Rd files:

```
patchRdFiles(name="test")
```

8) Checking package again

```
# CHECK PACKAGE AGAIN
path <- "package/test"
expr <- paste("R CMD check", path)
shell(expr, intern=FALSE)
```

Again the truncated output of R CMD check. The Rd file in question passed the check now. The current error is caused by an incomplete `./package/test/man/test-package.Rd`, which is fine at this point

```
[...]
Warning: parse error in file 'test-Ex.R':
11: unexpected symbol
56: 
57: ~~ simple examples
              ^
* checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in 'test-Ex.R' failed
The error most likely occurred in:

> ### Name: test-package
> ### Title: What the package does (short line) ~~ package title ~~
> ### Aliases: test-package test
> ### Keywords: package
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
> ~~ simple examples of the most important functions ~~
Error: unexpected symbol in "~~ simple examples"
Execution halted
Warning message:
In shell(expr, intern = FALSE) :
  'R CMD check package/test' execution failed with error code 1
>
```

Comment: If no answer turns up you should file it as an issue to the developer ([https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues)). Some time ago I had a problem with roxygen2 ignoring indentation in examples, and they fixed it in the following version.

Comment: Great, thanks for the pointer. I've emailed the link to this post to Hadley, but filing a standardized issue might indeed be the better way.

Comment: Gave you tested https://github.com/hadley/roxygen3?. Edit: Well this was happened to be quite old question, bug is probably fixed already...

Comment: There is a syntax error in foo2.R: there are 2 closing braces in the examples section.

Comment: @GSee: thanks, I will have a look

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug that is fixed in recent versions of roxygen2.

Comment: what is the symbol for "new line" in roxygen2?

Answer (score 2):

A (more simple) [temporary fix](https://github.com/jeroenooms/roxygen/commit/32b8ac9e55d2973aa95c0e4faa4a3a8db3c930ab) is implemented in this branch: https://github.com/jeroenooms/roxygen/tree/patch_dontrun.

See the [commit](https://github.com/jeroenooms/roxygen/commit/32b8ac9e55d2973aa95c0e4faa4a3a8db3c930ab) for the change. Its a one-line fix. I have also sent a pull request to peter, so hopefully it will get adopted in the main package.

Comment: +1.  Since it's just a one-line fix, why not copy and paste it here so that others don't have to look through commits?